# Align Images without spacing horizontally and veritcally

Tags: html, css

I have a group of 4 images that I'm trying to align vertically and horizontally.

The problem:

#### I cant get ride of a a small vertical spacing between them.

Please check out the issue reproduced in <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/cB2NM/)</kbd>

html:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href=""><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt=""></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href=""><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt=""></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href=""><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt=""></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href=""><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt=""></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
* {margin:0; padding: 0;}
div {width: 200px; height: 200px;}
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

It seems pretty simple, but I haven't been able to get ride of spacing other than manually specify the height to `100px`, which isn't responsive and so not viable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align:top` on the `img` elements will remove the gap. The default is `baseline`.

As a side note, `bottom` and `middle` work too.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/FSTcJ/)

```
img {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Adding `display:block` to the `img` elements works too. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/3v8cL/)

```
img {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
margin: 0 auto;
border: 0px;

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have text in this you can just say

```
ul {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

This eliminates the space, see modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cB2NM/2/)