# Unwanted space below image

Tags: html, css

This is my webcam: http://flamencopeko.net/cam.php

Source: http://flamencopeko.net/cam.txt

All the html5, css3 and js is in this one file.

After I upgraded it from XHTML to HTML5 there is this unwanted space below the image. You will see it as a yellow line when hovering.

Any css I'm missing?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229173/align-images-without-spacing-horizontally-and-veritcally/20229212#20229212)

Comment: you could use display block on the image

Comment: or you can add a float:left;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:block;` to the image.