# Overlap the image on hover

Tags: css

i want to show a hidden div when a photo is hovered, the problem is that the hidden divs got a background color, and when i hover some photo, the background still hidden.

I tried to put z-index 0 on the principal div, and z-index 1000 on the hidden div, but still not working.

How can i change that, and what am i doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/r7zhn50L/

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="photos">
<div class="a-img">
<img src="http://www.jamsadr.com/files/Professional/1fb60f23-00d5-4c43-a552-63321c9ed969/Presentation/HighResPhoto/Person-Donald-900x1080.jpg" width="180" height="250" />
<div class="a-hover">sdfsdf</div>
</div>

<div class="a-img">
<img src="http://www.jamsadr.com/files/Professional/1fb60f23-00d5-4c43-a552-63321c9ed969/Presentation/HighResPhoto/Person-Donald-900x1080.jpg" width="180" height="250" />
<div class="a-hover">sdfsdf</div>
</div>

<div class="a-img">
<img src="http://www.jamsadr.com/files/Professional/1fb60f23-00d5-4c43-a552-63321c9ed969/Presentation/HighResPhoto/Person-Donald-900x1080.jpg" width="180" height="250" />
<div class="a-hover">sdfsdf</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.photos .a-img{
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
z-index:0;
}

.photos .a-hover{
width:180px;
height:250px;
background-color:red;
margin-top:-250px;
display:none;
z-index:1000;
}

.photos .a-img:hover .a-hover{
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `z-index` property [only applies to positioned elements.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#layers)

You could add `position: relative` to the element. [(updated example)](http://jsfiddle.net/9w94ytd9/)

```
.photos .a-hover {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

Also, you need to remove the gap resulting from the inline `img` element's baseline alignment. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229173/align-images-without-spacing-horizontally-and-veritcally/20229212#20229212) is relevant.

---

The approach you are currently using only works for elements with fixed dimensions. I'd suggest using an approach that will work with dynamically varying dimensions: [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/f16x3wy7/)

```
.photos .a-img {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.photos .a-hover {
    background-color: #f00;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
.photos .a-img:hover .a-hover {
    display: block;
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322548/black-transparent-overlay-on-image-hover-with-only-css/18322705#18322705) might actually be helpful too.

Comment: I was too slow to answer :) [have this fiddle with a transition using `opacity`](http://jsfiddle.net/s0rveumo/) - the `display: block` on the image removes that baseline gap.

Comment: [and here is another example](http://jsfiddle.net/a3jtvn6x/) that positions the overlay with `position: absolute`. No need for negative margins.